# How to create an aspect on class, that is not a bean using Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I work on an legacy application, where Spring AOP (namely `ProxyFactoryBean`) is used.

I need to add an aspect around a method of a certain class. This class is **not** a bean however. 
The AspecjJ pointcut expression would be like this:

`execution(* xyz.package.Class.method())`

I created a `MethodInterceptor` and `AspectJExpressionPointcut`, but I don't know how make those two work together.

**EDIT**:
I do not have source code for this class, it is a 3rd party library. The instances of this class are not created by me, neither in source code, nor in spring configuration as beans. It is used internally by the library.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you not wrap the class in something that *is* a bean?

Comment: Well, I have connection pool, that is the bean and all it's internal objects are created withing this bean (no setters). I want to create logging aspect, that will log time it takes to obtain connection from the database. It's the method of one of those internal objects.

Comment: So currently, how do you obtain a reference to (an instance of) this class? Anyway I think with AspectJ and some AroundAdvice you would be able to do some profiling on this application. Spring is not required to use AspectJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use load-time weaving with full AspectJ support as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw), it doesn't require access to the source of classes being advised nor control over their instantiation (though it requires `<context:load-time-weaver />` and presence of the weaver itself using `-javaagent:...` or [other methods](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-environments)).

Answer (score 3):

Try `@Configurable`. It is explained in [this docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html).

> The @Configurable annotation marks a class as eligible for Spring-driven configuration

(you'd need `<context:load-time-weaver />`)

**Update**
You can make a 3rd party component a bean by listing it in `applicationContext.xml` as `<bean class=".." />` (you don't need `@Configurable` with that)

Comment: I do not have source for this class, it's 3rd party library.

Comment: then why not add it to applicationContext.xml ? (see my update)

Comment: Ok, but how can I add @Configurable on bean created like that?

Comment: you don't need @Configurable with this option - the class is already a bean

Comment: I updated the question with more details. Sadly, I think this approach is not going to help me,