# Spring AOP on objects created by factories which are beans

Tags: java, spring-aop

I have a piece of Spring AOP advice which is not triggering when the auth(..) method is called:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut="execution(* auth(..))",
        returning="result")
public void trigger(final Boolean result) {
    System.out.println("I was triggered " + result);
}
```

This is because the Authenticator object with the Auth method is not a Spring bean, but it is created by a factory which is a Spring bean:

```
    <bean id="passwordUserAuthFact" class="foo.bar.PasswordAuthFactory">
    ...
    </bean>

    <bean id="server" class="foo.bar.Server">
       <property name="authFactory" ref="passwordUserAuthFact"/>
       ...
    </bean>
```

So when the application does:

```
 session.authenticator = server.getAuthFactory().create();
```

... `session.authenticator` is an unproxied plain PasswordAuthFactory, and AOP isn't going to happen on it.

It seems to me that it should be possible to tell Spring about beans which are factories, so that it can wrap the factory in a proxy, such that objects returned by `create()` are themselves wrapped in an AOP proxy.

That is, Spring would dynamically create a wrapper around my factory like this:

```
public Foo create() {
    Foo instance = target.create();
    return wrapWithAopProxy(instance);
}
```

But I can't see a ready-made way to do that.

I would prefer not to make my classes Spring-aware. The factory class itself is third-party, so I would prefer a solution in which I don't change its source.

Is there a common pattern to achieve this? Or a better approach to the problem?

Comment: hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470014/how-to-create-an-aspect-on-class-that-is-not-a-bean-using-spring-aop) helps

Comment: Somewhat - it's saying "you can't do this with proxying, use load-time weaving". Will see if anyone says different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You main alternative, would be to go with programmatic aspect definition since you cannot play with the sources.

Implement a new authentication factory decorator that wraps your old authentication factory. The former would mainly delegate authenticator creation to the latter, then wraps the returned object with a `ProxyBean` and register the needed advice(s).

Sprig enables these beans to be loosely coupled and the `authenticator` POJO a non-managed bean. In below samples, I only aim to provide a glance view on how this can be done leaving implementation details up to your application:

- Here down a fake `Authenticator`:

  ```
  public class Authenticator
  {
      private String name;

      public Authenticator( String name )
      {
          this.name = name;
      }

      public void authenticate( Object subject )
      {
          System.out.println( subject + " is being authenticated by: " + name );
      }
  }
  ```
- Supposing that your `AuthFactory` interface looks like below:

  ```
  public interface AuthFactory 
  {
      Authenticator create();
  }
  ```
- It's legacy implementation, the one providing non managed authentication is as follows:

  ```
  public class AuthenticationFactory implements AuthFactory
  {
      @Override
      public Authenticator create()
      {
          return new Authenticator("mocked-authenticator");
      }
  }
  ```
- Create a new `MethodInterceptor` (note that you may need *aopalliance* dependency) that encapsulates your advice logic:

  ```
  public class AuthenticationAdvise implements MethodInterceptor
  {
      @Override
      public Object invoke( MethodInvocation methodInvocation ) throws Throwable
      {
          System.out.println("Before invocation..."); // Your advice logic goes here
          return methodInvocation.proceed();
      }
  }
  ```
- Create a new authentication provider decorator, which will be a *Spring managed bean*:

  ```
  public class AuthenticationFactoryDecorator implements AuthFactory {

      private AuthFactory authenticationFactoryDelegate;

      private MethodInterceptor interceptor;

      public AuthenticationFactoryDecorator( final AuthFactory authenticationFactoryDelegate, final MethodInterceptor interceptor )
      {
          this.authenticationFactoryDelegate = authenticationFactoryDelegate;
          this.interceptor = interceptor;
      }

      @Override
      public Authenticator create()
      {
           // Create the needed pointcut
          NameMatchMethodPointcut pc = new NameMatchMethodPointcut();
          pc.addMethodName("authenticate");
          // Get an authenticator from your legacy class
          Authenticator auth = authenticationFactoryDelegate.create();
          // Create a new Proxy wrapping your authFactory with the needed pointcut and advice
          ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory(auth);
          proxyFactory.addAdvice(interceptor);
          return (Authenticator) proxyFactory.getProxy();
      }
  }
  ```
- Register the new `AuthFactory` bean as a Spring component and wire it with your advice and legacy factory beans (e.g. *beans.xml*):

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

      <bean id="legacyAuthFactory" class="some.package.AuthenticationFactory"/>

      <bean id="interceptor" class="some.package.AuthenticationFactoryAdvise"/>

      <bean id="authFactory" class="some.package.AuthenticationFactoryDecorator">
          <constructor-arg name="authenticationFactoryDelegate" ref="legacyAuthFactory"/>
          <constructor-arg name="interceptor" ref="interceptor"/>
      </bean>

  </beans>
  ```

Now your are free to pull the *authFactory* bean from the Spring Application Context and use it to instantiate new authenticator objects:

```
public class MainAuthentication
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext  applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/beans.xml");
        AuthFactory factory = applicationContext.getBean("authFactory", AuthFactory.class);
        Authenticator authenticator = factory.create();
        authenticator.authenticate(new MockSubject());
    }

    private static class MockSubject
    {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MockSubject";
        }
    }
}
```

Executing below main class, note that you are dealing with a new proxied authenticator instance which is wrapped with your advice logic, as the output shows:

> Before invocation...
>
> MockSubject is being authenticated!!!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You've put a lot of time and effort in. Will give it a couple of days in case there are any further comments, before accepting.

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to suggest even improvements if any :)